# Google sheet separate log page with sellected columns script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, timestamp

I have a Google Sheet problem. My main page (which name is "MAIN", collects its data from other sheets.
So, 'MAIN' sheet looks like this:
[MAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrUzF.jpg)

I want to create a separate log page, which collects only "MAIN" sheets data when ever somebody change his hotel, next to his name. (Hotel column is 4th on the MAIN sheet)

..So "LogSheet" needs to collect 1st second and 4th column with timestamp..

so at the end there will be a list (who went, which hotell and when). it needs to be like this,
[LogSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vez4a.jpg)
but I couldnt write it :/

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var sheetsToWatch = ["MAIN"];
  var changelogSheetName = ["LogSheet"];

  var timestamp = new Date();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  
  if(col === 4 && row > 1 && e.source.sheetsToWatch() .getName() === "MAIN" ){
  e.changelogSheetName().getRange('MAIN', row,1).setValue(new Date());
  }   

 }
```

Comment: Please improve the quality of your question and I think the solution will come very quickly . If it is difficult for you to describe the question, feel free to post some images with the input and the expected output. Showing exactly the structure of the sheet and all the names. Even better create a copy of your file and share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

### There is some confusion about the usage of [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) and variables

1. Variables (including arrays) are called without `()` - `()` are reserved for calls of functions
2. If your variable cntains only one value, not an array - there is no need to put it in `[]` brackets. `[]` brackets designate a variable as an array and it needs to be proceeded differently.
3. To verify either a sheet is contained in an array of sheetnames, you need to use e.g. [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead of `==`
4. `e.source` returns you the spreadsheet in which the edit has taken place. When querying for `e.source.getActiveSheet()` you will obtain in most situations correctly the sheet in which the edit took place, but to account for exceptions it is better to use the event object `range` together with the method https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet
5. The method[getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column) expects rows, columns and optionally row and column numbers - not sheet names as variables.

**Please have a look at the modifications in the following samples.**

Sample with a sheet array

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var sheetsToWatch = ["MAIN", "add another sheet if desired" ];
  var changelogSheetName = "LogSheet";
  var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  Logger.log(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  if(col === 4 && row > 1 && sheetsToWatch.indexOf(sheetName)!=-1){
    logSheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
    //do whatever else you want
  }     
}
```

Sample with a single sheet as a variable

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var sheetsToWatch = "MAIN";
  var changelogSheetName = "LogSheet";
  var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  Logger.log(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  if(col === 4 && row > 1 && sheetsToWatch ==sheetName){
    logSheet.getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
    //do whatever else you want
  }     
}
```

Please refer to Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) and [Guides](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) for better understanding.

UPDATE

For your case, the most convenient is to retrieve values from the edited row and append them in the desired order to `LogSheet`

**Sample**

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var sheetsToWatch = "MAIN";
  var changelogSheetName = "LogSheet";
  var logSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(changelogSheetName);
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if(col === 4 && row > 1 && sheetsToWatch ==sheetName){
    var values = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4).getValues()[0];
    logSheet.appendRow([new Date(), values[0], values[1], values[3]]);
  }     
}
```

Comment: Very nice explanation!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It really helped me to learn.
*
But now, The LogSheet isnt a log list.
*
If the Change happens on the 9th row of 'MAIN',
 it apears at 9'th row of 'LogSheet'.
*


 But what I realy want is, a sumary list - a log file of all changes. Like a history check. Who went X hotel previously.. When did it happen, maybe couple of times all of it... And only trigger will be 'MAIN's 4th column, If somebody change it; it needs to capture automatcly that cells (on the picture I updated)

Comment: I do not quite understand what data exactly you want to retrieve and where to set, but I hope it helps you to know that there is a event object `e.oldValue` that allows you to retrieve the old hotel name (before it was changed) and `e.value` which corresponds to the new value. `getRange()` allows you to specify the row and column from which you want to get values or where you want to set values. I hope this is helpful for you! If not, please try to modify your question in such a way (with defined samples) that your issue becomes clearer.

Comment: This helps me alot, but still they are not in order. I create small example of my data sheet on this link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ye4ZcXA5viuAol0aC_f1YDRaLAD5rxRSAFv4BKkQRkE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you need to make the spreadsheet publicly available so I can open it.